# How to properly use RadzenRequiredValidator to Radzen Components

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, radzen

I just started using Radzen components for my Blazor Server Side app.
I found out that there are very few information regarding the title above and how to properly fix or implement validations.

So **i listed below** what should be the correct implementation on the most common components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is the correct way of using Radzen Validators?

1. You should first read the documentations regarding the components you are using.
2. Check first the examples and usages.

Now, let us say you already completed the two items mentioned above and still the validations are not working properly.

> Any components that can be validated should use the property **@bind-Value** instead of **Value**

Yes, you read it right. Using **@bind-Value** will fix all of my problems for components below:

- RadzenTextBox
- RadzenDatePicker
- RadzenNumeric

> You can also try this to other components that can be validated

Below are the examples:

For **RadzenDatePicker:** *(below is using Inline Calendar, if you are not using the inline Calendar then you should validate the control the same as **RadzenTextBox** validation)*

```
<RadzenDatePicker Name="DTPicker" Max="DateTime.Today" Inline="true" TValue="DateTime?" @bind-Value=@ValueDate Change=@OnChangeEventMethod>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <RadzenButton title="Clear Selected Date" Variant="Variant.Flat" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Click=@(args => OnClickDatePicker(args)) Text="Clear" class="my-3 w-100" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</RadzenDatePicker>
<RadzenRequiredValidator Component="DTPicker" DefaultValue="null" Text="This field is required" />
```

If your **DateTime** property is **nullable** then you should declare `DefaultValue="null"`.

- This will properly validate your component

If your property is not nullable then you can specify the default value yourself. Example: `DefaultValue="DateTime.Min"`.

> You can also check first if the validation will still work if you did
> not define a **DefaultValue**

> Note: **RadzenDatePicker's** `Name="DTPicker"` should also be the same
> for **RadzenRequiredValidator's** `Component="DTPicker"`.
> This is also the same to other components like **RadzenTextBox** and **RadzenNumeric**

For **RadzenTextBox**:

```
<RadzenTextBox Name="MyTextBox" Change=@(args => OnChange(args)) @bind-Value=@TextBoxValueProp />
<RadzenRequiredValidator Component="MyTextBox" Text="This field is required"/>
```

As you can see, the default value for any textbox is **string** so by default we do not need to define:

- **RadzenTextBox's** `TValue` and
- **RadzenRequiredValidator's** `DefaultValue`

For **RadzenNumeric**:

```
<RadzenNumeric Name="MyNumBox" TValue="int?" Change=@(args => OnChange(args)) @bind-Value=@ValueIntProp />
<RadzenRequiredValidator Component="MyNumBox" DefaultValue="null" Text="This field is required"/>
```

On this example, we want our component to accept values greater than or equal to 0. To validate, `@ValueIntProp` should be in **nullable type** and `TValue` should also be in **nullable type** :

- **ValueIntProp** should be declared as `private int? ValueIntProp { get; set; }` and
- **RadzenNumeric** should be `TValue="int?"` and
- **RadzenRequiredValidator** should be `DefaultValue="null"`

With this validation, it will check if the current value is null, if the User try to submit the form then it will show the validation error

Finally:

> For the validations above to work, those components should be inside
> the `RadzenTemplateForm` element

Example:

```
<RadzenTemplateForm Data="@order" Submit="@((OrderClass args) => { Submit(args); })">
    <RadzenNumeric Name="MyNumBox" TValue="int?" Change=@(args => OnChange(args)) @bind-Value=@order.Count />
    <RadzenRequiredValidator Component="MyNumBox" DefaultValue="null" Text="This field is required"/>
</RadzenTemplateForm>
@code {
    public class OrderClass
    {
        public int? Count { get; set; }
    }

    void Submit(OrderClass arg)
    {
        //TODO - add your code below
    }

    OrderClass order = new OrderClass();
}
```

For more info, read the documentations below:

- [RadzenTemplateForm](https://blazor.radzen.com/templateform)
- [RadzenDatePicker](https://blazor.radzen.com/datepicker)
- [RadzenRequiredValidator](https://blazor.radzen.com/requiredvalidator)
- [RadzenTextBox](https://blazor.radzen.com/textbox)
- [RadzenNumeric](https://blazor.radzen.com/numeric)
- https://forum.radzen.com/latest

Let me know on the comments if you have any questions or other suggestions